# If $\mathbb P_{Y|X\in A}(B):=\mathbb P(Y\in B \ | \ X \in A)$ can we explicitly define the r.v. $(Y|X\in A)$?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-probability

When introducing conditional expectation, one can define $\mathbb P_{Y|X\in A}(B):=\mathbb P(Y\in B \ | \ X \in A)$ which is itself a law. I was wondering if there is a way to define a random variable which has it as its law. So

\begin{align*} 
(Y|X\in A): \Omega & \to \mathbb R 
\\ \omega & \mapsto ? 
\\ &  
\end{align*}

Comment: No. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: @Did: Why "no" ?

Comment: Because this is never done and because there are some obstacles to do it, to begin with, what is the probability space on which this random variable would be defined?